# Create new df and record percentage by groups in R

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), amount = c(11L, 9L, 5L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 13L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 18L, 16L, 1L, 14L, 
15L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 6L, 
8L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 18L, 16L, 1L, 14L, 15L, 
13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 
17L, 16L, 8L), decile = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), time = c(2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("name", "amount", "decile", 
"time"), row.names = c(NA, -78L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), amount = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), decile = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("name", "amount", "decile", "time"
)), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

I wish to produce a summary table detailing a count of the number of items by decile. One solution is listed below:

```
data.frame(table(df$decile))
```

Alongside this, I want to add an additional column which records the percentage of 'names' (essential rows) which have an 'amount' greater or equal to 10 BY decile.

Any ideas how to complete my coding?

Comment: Is there some connection between your question about percentages and the one with `data.frame(table(df$decile))`?

Comment: @JuliusVainora - it's the same piece of work, just a different topic.

Comment: @ MartijnVanAttekum answer is helpful. But I really want the count and percentage in one dataframe. Any other approaches I should try?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(decile) %>% summarize(mean(amount>=10))

    decile      `mean(amount >= 10)`
    <int>                <dbl>
 1      1                0.556
 2      2                0.444
 3      3                0.556
 4      4                0.667
 5      5                0.667
 6      6                0.667
 7      7                0.5  
 8      8                0.333
 9      9                0.667
10     10                0.667
```

Calculates per decile how many rows have an `amount` value >= 10. Is that what you want? (do you mean percentage of "rows" rather than "names"?)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnVanAttekum can I ask why it produces the table but I get the error: Error: unexpected symbol in "decile `sum(amount >= 10)/n()`" ?

Comment: I simplified the answer later to just use mean instead of sum/n. Does that work for you?